# Any chance to register a callback URL for In App Purchase at iTunes Connect for consumable products?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

We're reading the receipt from StoreKit an sending the NSData to our server. There we're verifying the the data with https://github.com/chrismaddern/iOS-Receipt-Validator-PHP afterwards we make the booking transaction in our cloud system and mark the transaction as completed. But what if the data connection of the client (user) breaks during the buying transaction. Then we'll never get the request with the receipt data and we can't complete the process at our server side. So it would be perfectly if apple submits a callback for every new transaction at In App Purchase. So we can check in time when a customers bought a product at the app. Ideas?

Comment: Did you get a response to your question since its been over a year?

Comment: me too looking for answer on this question.